# Generate Dynamic StackedBarChart

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to create dynamic StackedBarChart from Java Object. I tried this code:

**Java Object:**

```
public class EventsObj
{
    private String date;
    private int info;
    private int error;
    private int warning;
    private int critical;

    public EventsObj()
    {
    }

    public EventsObj(String date, int info, int error, int warning, int critical)
    {
        this.date = date;
        this.info = info;
        this.error = error;
        this.warning = warning;
        this.critical = critical;
    }

    public String getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getInfo()
    {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(int info)
    {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public int getError()
    {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(int error)
    {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public int getWarning()
    {
        return warning;
    }

    public void setWarning(int warning)
    {
        this.warning = warning;
    }

    public int getCritical()
    {
        return critical;
    }

    public void setCritical(int critical)
    {
        this.critical = critical;
    }
}
```

Java code:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
    private StackedBarChart<String, Number> stackedChart;
    private List<EventsObj> eventsObj;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        createStackedChart();
        List<EventsObj> testData = generateTestData();

        addStackedChartData(testData);

        HBox hb = new HBox(20);
        hb.setPadding(new Insets(10, 20, 20, 40));
        hb.getChildren().add(stackedChart);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hb);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void createStackedChart()
    {
        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Days");
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

        stackedChart = new StackedBarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        stackedChart.setCategoryGap(20);
        stackedChart.setMinSize(500, 400);
        stackedChart.setMaxSize(500, 400);
    }

    private List<EventsObj> generateTestData()
    {
        eventsObj = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            eventsObj.add(new EventsObj(String.valueOf(randomDate()), random(2, 60), random(2, 60), random(2, 60), random(2, 60)));
        }

        return eventsObj;
    }

    public static int random(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
    {
        return (lowerBound + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (upperBound - lowerBound)));
    }

    private LocalDate randomDate()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int minDay = (int) LocalDate.of(1900, 1, 1).toEpochDay();
        int maxDay = (int) LocalDate.of(2015, 1, 1).toEpochDay();
        long randomDay = minDay + random.nextInt(maxDay - minDay);

        LocalDate randomBirthDate = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(randomDay);

        return randomBirthDate;
    }

    private void addStackedChartData(List<EventsObj> data)
    {
        ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> observableArrayList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> observabt = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (EventsObj data1 : data)
        {
            final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
            EventsObj get = data1;
            series1.setName(get.getDate());
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(get.getDate(), get.getInfo()));
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(get.getDate(), get.getWarning()));
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(get.getDate(), get.getCritical()));
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(get.getDate(), get.getError()));
            observabt.addAll(series1);
        }

        stackedChart.getData().addAll(observabt);
    }
}
```

I need to generate a `StackedBarChart` that contains one bar for every day that contains different parts for the event types `Info`, `Warning`, `Critical` and `Error`. But for some reason I can't get it right. It should be something like this:

[image]

Countries should be replaced by dates and years should be replaced by event types.

Can you help me fix the code?

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a chart that has one column per date and each column should contain parts `Info`, `Warning`, `Error` and `Critical`. To do this you need to create a different series for each event type. However you use `date` as series name and column name. You need to change this:

```
private static XYChart.Series<String, Number> createSeries(String name) {
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series.setName(name);
    return series;
}

private void addStackedChartData(List<EventsObj> data) {
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> infoSeries = createSeries("Info");
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> warningSeries = createSeries("Warning");
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> criticalSeries = createSeries("Critical");
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> errorSeries = createSeries("Error");

    for (EventsObj data1 : data) {
        String date = data1.getDate();
        infoSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(date, data1.getInfo()));
        warningSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(date, data1.getWarning()));
        errorSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(date, data1.getError()));
        criticalSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(date, data1.getCritical()));
    }
    stackedChart.getData().setAll(errorSeries, warningSeries, infoSeries, criticalSeries);
}
```

The series has to be used this way:

```
series.setName(<Color Key>);
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(<Column>, <Bar Size>));
```

Comment: I get this result:http://i67.tinypic.com/2gy6o8i.png  This result is totally wrong

Comment: @PeterPenzov: But that's one column per event type, just as described in the question. What's wrong with that? Please improve the description in the question, since it's hard to tell, what exactly you want. What should be the "color keys" (= Years in the example); what should be on the x-axis (= countries in the example)?